# can I use a partial entity to save with typeorm?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

So I have this table structure

```sql
--changeset 0004-order:ccushing
create table if not exists "order"."order"
(
    id          uuid primary key                                          not null default uuid_generate_v4(),
    state       uuid references "order".order_status
);

--changeset 0004-h0-table-order_event_type:ccushing
create table if not exists "order".order_event_type
(
    id          uuid primary key                                          not null default uuid_generate_v4(),
    key         text unique                                               not null
);

--changeset 0004-h1-table-order_event:ccushing
create table if not exists "order".order_event
(
    id          uuid primary key                                          not null default uuid_generate_v4(),
    order_id    uuid                                                      not null references "order"."order" (id),
    event_type  uuid                                                      not null references "order".order_event_type (id),
    event       jsonb                                                     not null,
    unique (order_id, event),
    unique (order_id, event_type)
);
```

I want to create a new `OrderEventEntity`, but I don't want to load `Order` when doing it, since I'll just be getting the `order_id` in the event.

```
@Entity('order.order_event')
export default class OrderEventEntity implements Identifiable<string> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'uuid' })
  readonly id!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => OrderEventTypeEntity, ({ event }) => event)
  readonly eventType!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => OrderEntity, ({ events }) => events)
  readonly order!: OrderEntity;
}
```

am I able to do

```
const order = new Order({ id: 1234 })
repo.save( new OrderEventEntity({ order: order, ... })
```

or similar (maybe some partial load) without losing the OneToMany? but still only having the order id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Define `order_id` column in your `OrderEventEntity`

```
@Entity('order.order_event')
export default class OrderEventEntity implements Identifiable<string> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'uuid' })
  readonly id!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => OrderEventTypeEntity, ({ event }) => event)
  readonly eventType!: string;

  @Column()
  order_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => OrderEntity, ({ events }) => events)
  readonly order!: OrderEntity;
}
```

2. Use force cast tricky

```
const order = { id: 1234 } as Order;
repo.save( new OrderEventEntity({ order: order, ... })
```

Comment: I should have guessed this, but it doesn't actually care if the object is from a loaded instance.